# How to integrate AdMob ads in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, admob, xcode8

Constantly struggling to implement AdMob ads into my iOS app manually but no luck - I have inserted GoogleMobileAds.framework in project folder where the ViewController.swift and AppDelegate.swift was & added all required frameworks under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries', changed Bitcode to 'NO' in Build Settings

Typed 'import GoogleMobileAds' in ViewControllerSwift.swift but it states 'No such module GoogleMobileAds'

What am I missing here? Im using XCode 8.3.3 and Swift 3

Comment: If you would try to use PODs everything will work for you.
Have you try that ?

Answer (score 1):

Admob is part of Firebase now so install pod files below and then try to `import GoogleMobileAds`

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Comment: Can you guide me step by step? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Read the manuals more carefully

1. install cocoapods https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

`$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

2.

```
$ cd your-project directory
$ pod init
```

3. Edit PodFile: add this code inside target rows

> ```
> pod 'Firebase/Core'
> pod 'Firebase/Admob'
> ```

4.

```
$ pod install
$ open your-project.xcworkspace
```